# How to add fridge waterline to washer line

Tags: water, refrigerator

I have fridge in my laundry room and would like to add water line to fridge. I thought it would be easy but cannot find adaptor/connector/splitter for that. Can you advise what should I buy? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I've run across hoses that are specified for whatever reason to not be usable for potable drinking water, like your fridge would use. If your washer hoses are not rated for potable use, the hoses may contaminate the fridge's water. You might do better to make a connection in the cold water pipe in the wall itself, if you're allowed to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a splitter in your picture already.  Idk what for, a steam dryer?  Get another one, so that you can attach a total of three things to cold water. Then use an adapter to a fridge line [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-4-in-FHT-x-1-4-in-O-D-Compression-Brass-Adapter-Fitting-801789/207176917).  It's 3/4 FHT X 1/4 compression.

**Edit** - further to a comment from @Triplefault above, here is a way to do essentially the same thing but avoid the issue of hoses not meant for potable water.  *Just use brass parts instead of hoses for the splitters.*

For example you could do it with [an all-brass manifold with individual shutoffs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086MCB2KZ).  That would replace both splitters and feed the washer, dryer and fridge.  You would connect the FHT-to-3/8 adapter directly to the manifold.

But that particular one won't fit in the plastic laundry outlet box you've got there, so you could hunt around for one that will, or you could use that one with a short leader like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D51VBFS) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8V2R8VR).

It will look, um, unprofessional? and I agree it might be best to do it properly in the wall .... but if you want to avoid or postpone that, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Your fridge would need 1/4 inch pipe.

This adapter might work for you

1/2" female IPS slip joint x 1/2" male IPS slip joint x 1/4" male compression. You might also want a 1/4 inch shut off valve in the line to the fridge.

Found on https://www.plumbingsupply.com/quick-tee-adapter.html

[image: adapter]